# Define local file

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

This project has to rely on older version of a SAP system. As a result some of the latest features do not work. I would like to have the "minutesStep" property of the latest "TimePicker" version, so I went to the source code and copied the latest TimePicker controls code to our old project.

I am having issues as "TimePicker" relies on the new version of "TimePickersliders" as well. I need to copy its source code as well. However I fail to make the "TimePicker" use the new "TimePickerslider" source code which I copied to the project as well.

```
sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 
            'sap/m/InputBase', 
            'sap/m/MaskInput', 
            'sap/m/MaskInputRule', 
            'sap/m/ResponsivePopover', 
            'sap/ui/core/EnabledPropagator', 
            'sap/ui/core/IconPool', 
            'sap/ui/model/type/Time', 
            './TimePickerSliders'], // Here is the problem. 
    function(jQuery, InputBase, MaskInput, MaskInputRule, ResponsivePopover, EnabledPropagator, IconPool, TimeModel, TimePickerSliders) {
```

What should be the './TimePickerSliders' path, so that it includes the file in my project? Its in the same folder, but it just fails to pick it up.

Here is the Error I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'PROJECT_NAME/controls/MyTimePicker.js' from ./controls/MyTimePicker.js: Error: failed to load 'PROJECT_NAME/controls/Slider.js' from ./controls/Sliders.js: Error: failed to load 'PROJECT_NAME/controls/VisibleItem.js' from ./controls/VisibleItem.js: Error: failed to load 'PROJECT_NAME/controls/library.js' from ./controls/library.js: 404 - NOT FOUND

Is this even possible, reasonable or legal? I seem to be missing some other files as well.

Comment: This might be helpful https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1dfab2e19fc0479d9dfcefc28d3642f1.html

Answer (score 0):

If `TimePickerSliders` is a .js file located in your `controls` folder (I assume its on the same level as `view` and `controller` folders), try to call it like follows:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    ...
    '<project-namespace>/controls/TimePickerSliders'], 
function(jQuery, InputBase, MaskInput, MaskInputRule, ResponsivePopover, EnabledPropagator, IconPool, TimeModel, TimePickerSliders) {
```